# Near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

I am faced with problem:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT tags FROM appDb_table_project WHERE SELECT DISTINCT tags
```

I have:

```
public static final String DB_NAME = "appDbProject";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DB_TABLE = "appDb_table_project";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String COLUMN_TAGS = "tags";

public SQLiteDatabase mDB;
public Cursor getTags() {
    String[] column = new String[] { COLUMN_TAGS };
    //return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, column, "SELECT DISTINCT tags", null, null, null, null);
    //return mDB.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] { COLUMN_TAGS }, null, null, COLUMN_TAGS, null, null, null);
    //String query ="SELECT DISTINCT tags FROM appDb_table_staff";
    //return mDB.rawQuery(query, null);
    return mDB.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] { COLUMN_TAGS }, null, null, COLUMN_TAGS, null, null, null);
}
```

I'm trying to use SELECT DISTINCT statement for my data in field "tags" and put it into String[], but I did not get.

```
Cursor cursor = db.getTags();
    String[] array = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String tag = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tags"));
        array[i] = tag;
        i++;
    }
    String[] from = array;
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textViewTags };
```

I tried different options, but forever I get this error in this line and inside of my method "getTags":

```
Cursor cursor = db.getTags();
```

What am I doing wrong?

upd:

Code that is actually being executed:
[code 1](http://pastebin.com/22Vu276i)
[code 2](http://pastebin.com/UgJsCvtH)

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` this: `WHERE SELECT DISTINCT tags`

Comment: The error mesage does not match the code. Show the code that is actually being executed.

Comment: I can read the text of the error, but I still can not figure out what is wrong. 
I tried to do as others do, but still nothing happened.

Comment: @CL there is a code in my question, which results in an error. `Cursor cursor = db.getTags();` and my method `getTags()`

Comment: The uncommented line in `getTags()` *cannot* generate this error.

Comment: @CL but there is an error ._.

Comment: But it was generated by a different version of your code.

Comment: As I said, remove `WHERE SELECT DISTINCT tags`

Comment: @CL Here my classes code: http://pastebin.com/22Vu276i  http://pastebin.com/UgJsCvtH

Comment: @BobMalooga How to remove? I do not quite understand.

Comment: Edit the question to show the version of the code that is actually being executed.

Comment: Don't add that WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the following line:

```
SELECT tags FROM appDb_table_project WHERE SELECT DISTINCT tags
```

to

```
SELECT tags FROM appDb_table_project
```

Answer (score -1):

Try add " space "

```
public Cursor getTags() {
String[] column = new String[] { COLUMN_TAGS };
//return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, column, " SELECT DISTINCT tags ", null, null, null, null);
//return mDB.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] { COLUMN_TAGS }, null, null, COLUMN_TAGS, null, null, null);
//String query =" SELECT DISTINCT tags FROM appDb_table_staff ";
//return mDB.rawQuery(query, null);
return mDB.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] { COLUMN_TAGS }, null, null, COLUMN_TAGS, null, null, null);
 }
```